# Field extension with transcendental number

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Is it something meaningful to write:
$\Bbb Q(t)$. Where $t$ is not algebraic. If so for which values it is meaningful and what it means.

Comment: $\;\Bbb Q(t)\;$ is the fractions field of the polynomial (integer domain) ring $\;\Bbb Q[t]\;$ . Why wouldn't it be meaningful?

Comment: For $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ it is meaningful. But is it the same for example for $\Bbb Q(\pi)$? Where the $\pi$ is transcendental.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ which contains $\pi$ as an element. Equivalently, $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ is the intersection of all subfields of $\mathbb{R}$ which contain $\pi$ as an element.

Comment: Yes. $\mathbb Q(s)$ in general means the set of all rational functions in $s$ with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$. Since $\pi$ is transcendental, $\mathbb Q(\pi)$ is isomorphic to the ring $\mathbb Q(t)$ of rational functions in an indeterminate, since $\pi$ satisfies no polynomial (so distinct rational functions evaluate to different values).

Comment: @quasi is there such field for any transcendental number?

Comment: @Gevorg Hmayakyan: Yes.${}{}{}{}$.

Comment: Is it easy to prove. Sorry may be it is trivial, but I can not understand this very well.

Comment: @Gevorg Hmayakyan: It's the same reasoning. Let $K$ be any field, and let $F$ be a subfield of $K$. Then for any element $t \in K$, we define $F(t)$ to be the intersection of all subfields of $K$ which contain $F$ as a subfield, and also contain $t$ as an element. For the definition of $F(t)$, it doesn't matter whether or not $t$ is algebraic over $F$

Comment: Thanks. Starting to understand.

Comment: @Gevorg Hmayakyan: Also,  look back at the comment by John Brevik which describes how to _represent_ the elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$. Every element of $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ can be expressed as $a(\pi)/b(\pi)$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ (i.e., $a,b$ are polynomials with rational coefficients), and $b \ne 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two distinct field constructions happening here. One is to recognize one field as a subfield of another $k\subseteq K,$ to find an element of the larger field $\alpha\in K$, and consider the smallest subfield of $K$ containing both the subfield $k$ and the element $\alpha.$ This field is denoted $k(\alpha).$

The other is to adjoin an indeterminate $t$ to an existing field $k$, giving the field of rational functions $k(t)$.

Both $k(t)$ and $k(\alpha)$ are extension fields of $k$. What they have in common and the reason for the common notation for them, is that $k(a)$ is the set of rational expressions in $a$ with coeffcients in $k$, for any symbol $a$.

The two operations yield isomorphic fields $k(t)\cong k(\alpha)$ if and only if $\alpha$ transcendental. This is essentially the definition of transcendental.

Conversely however, if $\alpha$ is *not* transcendental, $k(t)\not\cong k(\alpha).$ There is a relationship between them, which is that $k(t)$ is the field of fractions of the polynomial ring $k[t]$, and there is a ring homomorphism $k[t]\to k[\alpha]$, which is given by evaluation at $t=\alpha.$ But this does not extend to a field homomorphism $k(t)\to k(\alpha).$

So for example, $\mathbb{Q}(t)\cong\mathbb{Q}(\pi),$ as both are transcendental field extensions (extensions of infinite degree) of transcendence degree one. But $\mathbb{Q}(t)\not\cong\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}),$ as the latter is an extension of degree two; an algebraic extension.

Answer (score 2):

The ring $k[X]$ of polynomials over an integral domain $k$ is an integral domain. So you can built the quotient field $k(t):=Quot(k[t])$. 
(Observe that $\mathbb{Q}$ is an integral domain, so you can choose $k=\mathbb{Q}$).
If $t$ is algebraic $k(t)=k[t]$ holds.